# Setting environment variable to shell executed from perl script

Tags: shell, perl, environment-variables

I am running a perl file *a.pm* which invokes *b.sh* via system command.
Here, *b.sh* is using `find` utility whose path is */usr/local/bin*.

If I run `env` on shell directly on machine, I get output as below for `PATH` variable.

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/bin:/home/bin/samba::/home/venv/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
```

Thats why if I run the *b.sh* directly from shell, it is able to execute find utility.

Now, If I run *b.sh* via *a.pm* as mentioned earlier using `system()`, and when I print `PATH` env variable in *b.sh*, its coming as

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/bin:/home/perl5/bin
```

which does not have `/usr/local/bin`, and thats why `find` command is failing.

If I tried to print all ENV variables in perl before invoking `system(b.sh)`, PATH variable is not printed.

Now, I tried adding path variable in a.pm file as follows just before invoking system(b.sh).

```
$ENV{'PATH'} = '/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/';
```

Now, if I try to print all `ENV` variables in `perl` before invoking `system(b.sh)`, PATH variable is printed with above value.

Still executing the *a.pm* file, the PATH variable printed in *b.sh* is same:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/bin:/home/perl5/bin
```

How can I add corresponding path */usr/local/bin* to shell of *b.sh* invoked using *a.pm*?

Comment: How do you invoke your shell script? Does b.sh have a shebang? What is it?

Comment: I am using system(b.sh) in a.pm file. I can run b.sh directly from linux shell as well and then it works fine.

Comment: No program can ever change its parent process's environment variables. This is part of how environment variables work on UNIX in general -- they're copied from parent to child, never from child to parent.

Comment: ...mind, changing `$ENV{'PATH'}` _does_ change the `PATH` for future subprocesses started from that same Perl interpreter. A [mre] that we can run without changes to see if that isn't working would be an appropriate place to start.

Comment: I created a short shell script and Perl script and I can't reproduce your problem. PATH set via %ENV is correctly propagated to the `system` command.

Comment: Note that if you have an `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` that points to the name of a file that overrides `PATH`, that's one way for the shell started up by `system()` to have the PATH set by the parent process overridden.

Comment: I have the same issue in a perl script. Environment variables are not propagated to system command, don't understand why.

Comment: Actually, I have ran some tests in the meantime. My command is executed from a custom function that is called from another function that runs in a thread. I was setting the environment variable directly in the function that runs the custom executor, so just before calling the command. The environment variable was not propagating and I still don't understand why. I have made a test and set the environment variable directly at the beginning of the script, outside of any function and it now propagates. I guess it has something to do with threads, but I am not really familiar with perl...

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the Perl program is either modifying the path it gets from the shell that invokes it, or that you have left out a step somewhere. For example, if you invoke the Perl program from a different environment, it will likely have a different `PATH`.

You seemed to have found your answer though. Add the necessary directory to the PATH in the Perl program. But, you say this doesn't work. Again, I think there's some step that you haven't included. I suspect that the way in which you run system overwrites the PATH inherited from the parent.

For example, here's a small Perl program the merely runs a shell script:

```
#!perl
use v5.10;

$ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin';

say "PATH in Perl is $ENV{PATH}";
system( "sh ./pather.sh" );
```

The shell script echos the PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "PATH in shell:" $PATH
```

When I run this, both PATHs match:

```
PATH in Perl is /bin:/usr/bin
PATH in shell: /bin:/usr/bin
```

But, maybe the command in `system` is something else. The `-l` switch treats the shell as a login shell, so it will load the various profiles and whatnot:

```
system( "sh -l ./pather.sh" );
```

Now the PATH is different in the shell script because my particular profiles overwrote PATH:

```
PATH in Perl is /bin:/usr/bin
Path in shell: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/go/bin:...
```

Our answers can be more targeted you can produce a minimal working example where we see actual code that demonstrates the problem. Since we don't see what you actually run in `system`, we can only guess.